# How can I set “IsSiteAdmin” property true for a user via Webservice/REST API for Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive-for-business

The question actually is that whether or not an Admin (Company Administrator) assign a user(say himself) who is NOT a site user on a Site as Site Collection Admin for the OneDrive(my site) for other tenant users.

Let's say that admin is abc@mytenant@onmicrosoft.com and there is a user say pqr@mytenant@onmicrosoft.com. The OneDrive(my site) for this user would be;

```
https://mytenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/prq_onmicrosoft_com
```

Can I make abc@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com (who is NOT a site user on pqr@mytenant@onmicrosoft.com) a Site Collection Administrator on this site?

Much appreciated!

***NOTE:*** Currently, I am doing it via Powershell but I'm interested in doing it via APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do it using CSOM: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mimorr/archive/2014/01/22/adding-site-collection-admin-in-csom-in-a-sharepoint-2013-app.aspx

If you setup this example, and then run Fiddler to see how the CSOM code gets translated into REST calls, you should be able to get the REST call you need.